# nodemon stuck at "clean exit - waiting for changes before restart". Please find the attached screenshot

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

nodemon is stuck here and the server is not starting at localhost. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling ndemon.

```
PS D:\webdevnew> nodemon 
[nodemon] 2.0.7
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node ./routes/index.js`
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

Comment: Does the app start correctly when you are not using `nodemon`?

Comment: Try to pass your server script to nodemon as the first argument.